# Print neat progress bar from macOS terminal command prompt

Tags: c++, terminal, xterm

macOS terminal is of type `xterm-256color`. I'd like to print colored progress bar with special characters.

for example, I uses printf with the symbol `\xb0` to present the progress bar :

```
printf("%s", msg.c_str());

in debugger : 
(lldb) p msg
(const std::string) $0 = "[\xb0\xb0\xb0\xb0]"
```

But apparently, it prints invisible symbols. Any idea how to print `\xb0` in terminal ?

Furthermore, is there any way print messages that overrun the current line? I wish to show the progress bar advancing, and not printing it in multiple lines that each represent different percentage state.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well doing it from scratch is pretty cumbersome.

Why don't you use an existing library like [this](https://github.com/p-ranav/indicators), the code seems pretty straightforward.

You get all fancy progress bars, with color, and it seems pretty intuitive, and its very customizable.

(From the Github Repo, [here](https://github.com/p-ranav/indicators))

```
#include <indicators/progress_bar.hpp>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

int main() {
  using namespace indicators;

  ProgressBar bar{
    option::BarWidth{50},
    option::Start{"["},
    option::Fill{"="},
    option::Lead{">"},
    option::Remainder{" "},
    option::End{"]"},
    option::PostfixText{"Extracting Archive"},
    option::ForegroundColor{Color::green},
    option::FontStyles{std::vector<FontStyle>{FontStyle::bold}}
  };
  
  // Update bar state
  while (true) {
    bar.tick();
    if (bar.is_completed())
      break;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I can change the total length of the bar by changing the value of `option::BarWidth`, or make the fill to 0 by changing `option::Fill{"="}` to `option::Fill{"0"}`

Comment: Hi and thanks for you response ... Do you know if this library support both linux and windows terminals ?

Comment: @Zohar81 Yes, it works on linux and windows terminals.

Comment: I've tried to use the rocket symbol in windows, and it failed to define It although I'm using the standard cmd. any idea why ?

Comment: @Zohar81, the windows terminal does not support those characters unfortunately, it'll work for text or anything like that, but unfortunately no emojis. (Should have mentioned that before)